# function in struct does not do anything

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, struct

I have a simple struct to represent a percentage from left, top, right, bottom of an image to use for cropping:

```
struct RoiRect {
    unsigned int left;
    unsigned int top;
    unsigned int right;
    unsigned int bottom;

    bool isAllZero() {
        return left == 0 && top == 0 && left == 0 && bottom == 0;
    }

    void getCvRect(cv::Size cvSize, cv::Rect &cvRect) {
            int height = cvSize.height;
            int width = cvSize.width;

            int x = ((double)(left/height)*100);
            int y = ((double)(top/height)*100);
            int w = width - ((double)(right/width)*100);
            int h = height - ((double)(bottom/width)*100);

            cvRect.x = x;
            cvRect.y = y;
            cvRect.width = w;
            cvRect.height = h;
    }
};
```

I initialize this struct with values like 10,15,20,25. This means that an image should be cropped by 10% from its right side, 15% from its top and so on.

In another class I will call the `getCvRect` of the struct and pass in size of an image and also a raw `cv::Rect` object so the above function calculate the percentages and return a rectangle to be cropped from image:

```
//inside another function
cv::Rect rect; //rect to be calculated by getCvRect function of the struct
bool crop; //should crop or not? if all == zero then NOT!
if(!mRoiRect.isAllZero()) {
    crop = true;
    mRoiRect.getCvRect(mat.size(), rect);
}
```

But all the effort is in vain! I pass in a size as the first argument and I am pretty sure that the image size is e.g. 640x480...the `rect` object after the function call shows `640x480` ...so my function does absolutly nothing.

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix or better what is the smarter way of doing this task?

**The correct implementation would be (for anyone interested)**

```
    int x = ((double) left / 100) * width;
    int y = ((double) top / 100) * height;
    int w = width - ((double) right / 100) * width;
    int h = height - ((double) bottom / 100) * width;
```

Comment: Hint: `left/height` is executed as integer division

Comment: Voting to close. You have been active here long enough to understand minimal complete examples. (And they are as vital to development and testing as they are to the posting of questions.)

Comment: @Beta yep you are right...it was a simple mistake...I vote close myself too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the four lines:

```
        int x = ((double)(left/height)*100);
        int y = ((double)(top/height)*100);
        int w = width - ((double)(right/width)*100);
        int h = height - ((double)(bottom/width)*100);
```

here `left/height`, etc... all use integer division and then the result gets casted to a double. The effect is, of course, that `x` and `y` and both zero and `w == width` and `h == height`. What you meant to write was most likely

```
        int x = ((double) left)/height*100;
        int y = ((double) top)/height*100;
        int w = width - ((double) right)/width*100;
        int h = height - ((double) bottom)/width*100;
```

Comment: That jumped to my eye when I saw that

Answer (score 1):

a sample function that i have used maybe useful for improving your code

```
Rect shrinkRect(Rect rect, int width_percent, int height_percent)
{
    if (width_percent > 100) width_percent = 100;
    if (height_percent > 100) height_percent = 100;

    Rect newrect;
    newrect.width = (rect.width * width_percent) / 100;
    newrect.height = (rect.height * height_percent) / 100;
    newrect.x = rect.x + (rect.width - newrect.width) / 2;
    newrect.y = rect.y + (rect.height - newrect.height) / 2;

    return newrect;
}
```

usage: lets say you have a `Rect r = Rect(0,0,100,100)`

you want to shrink your rect %20

```
Rect shrinkedRect = shrinkRect(r, 80, 80)
```

shrinkedRect is (10,10,80,80)

you can give different values for `width_percent` and `height_percent`